# How to unsplit a strtok string in C?

Tags: c, strtok

I scanned in a text file and have split the string using strtok. The delimiter was all the punctuation characters. I'd like to now unsplit the file so it reverts back to its original state. Is there a way to do this? Or should i just load in the file again?

Comment: There's no way to "unsplit" the string, since you don't know which separator was used for the "split". Perhaps keep a separate copy of the string?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ahh okay, will do then. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, knock up your own implementation of strtok that instead of injecting nulls returns a string_span (pointer and length) describing the substring. Of course, you then have to use length delimited methods such as strncmp.

Answer (score 0):

For the single delimiter

```
char *unsplit(char *buff, char **argv, size_t size, int delimiter)
{
    size_t pos = 0;

    for (size_t index; index < size; index++)
    {
        strcpy(buff + pos, argv[index]);
        pos += strlen(argv[index]);
        if(index != size - 1) 
        {
            buff[pos++] = delimiter;
            buff[pos] = 0;
        }
    }
    return buff;
}

char *unsplitNULL(char *buff, char **argv, int delimiter)
{
    size_t pos = 0;

    while(*argv)
    {
        strcpy(buff + pos, *argv);
        pos += strlen(*argv++);
        if(*argv) 
        {
            buff[pos++] = delimiter;
            buff[pos] = 0;
        }
    }
    return buff;
}

int main()
{

    char *str[] = {"3443", "erte", "sdfdsffd", "wewere", NULL};
    char buff[100];
    printf("%s\n", unsplit(buff, str, 4, ','));
    printf("%s\n", unsplitNULL(buff, str, ','));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why an array of strings? `strtok` works on a single string: `"3443,erte,sdfdsffd,wewere"` and as far is I understand OP wants to split all the puntuaction characters (not only the delimiter `','`)

Comment: @KeineLust _strok_ is a way to _split_ (a string in several strings), here the goal is to **un**_split_ (separated strings into one string) ;-)

Comment: @bruno, I know, but how does this array of strings (the result of the split) can tell anything about which punctuator was used as separator in the original string?

Comment: @KeineLust it cannot as Some programmer dude said in a remark on the question, and this is why the ',' is given in argument by P__J__. Generally when we split the delimiters are removed and not present in the split result

Comment: @bruno then this doesn't answer the question, and is way too complicated, there is no need to `strcpy`: https://ideone.com/BeigK9

Comment: @KeineLust to not _strcpy_ the results of _strtok_ supposes the source never disappear or is never modified